# Factor gives non-factorized result

Tags: built-in-symbols, factorization

The `Factor` built-in function is usually idempotent, namely applying it twice gives the same result.  However, in the following example it is not.  Is that expected?  Somehow the need to simplify `Sin[x]Cot[x]` to `Cos[x]` seems to confuse the code responsible for factoring, so that the result is not factorized.

```
In[1]:= Factor[x (x + 1) + Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sin[x] (1 + Cot[x])]

Out[1]= x + x^2

In[2]:= Factor[%]

Out[2]= x (1 + x)
```

Is that expected?

Comment: from help it says **Factor applies only to the top algebraic level in an expression. You may have to use Map, or apply Factor again, to reach other levels.** and that what seems to have happened here.

Comment: You could do `Simplify@Factor[x (x+1)+Sin[x]+Cos[x]-Sin[x] (1+Cot[x])]` which gives `x (1+x)`  btw, this is the same thing that happens in Maple also.  But Mathematica does better on the factor part. But Maple also needed simplify, here is screen shot.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s95He.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the confusion that `Factor` encounters is that the sum has trig. functions in it. Since the default option is `Trig -> False`, it ignores the expression (other than expanding it).

But this works:

```
Factor[x (x + 1) + Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sin[x] (1 + Cot[x]), 
 Trig -> True]
(*  x (1 + x)  *)
```

(So does, oddly, `Factor[..., Extension -> All]`. And `Extension -> Sqrt[2]`.)